# Invariance of rank under diffeomorphism

Tags: calculus, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, submanifold, invariance

So I am kind of confused by this:

We have $U \subset \mathrm{R}^m$ and $V \subset \mathrm{R}^n$ as open sets. If $f: U \rightarrow V$ is a diffeomorphism then we essentially have $m=n$.

Same holds true if instead of open sets we are working with submanifolds, that is $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are submanifolds of dimension $m$ and $n$ then if $f:\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ is a diffeomorhism then $m=n$

However with arbitrary sets this is apparantly not true. Let $U \subset \mathrm{R}^m$ be an open set and $X \subset \mathrm{R}^n$ be an arbitrary set. Then if $f: U \rightarrow X$ is defined as a diffeomorphism then $m\le n$. My question is can then $f$ even be defined as a diffeomorphism? And if so, can some one comment on why this dimensional invariance fails here and what condition is needed to ensure dimensional invariance.

Thanks

EDIT
Maybe an example of a diffeomorphism from an open subset to an arbitrary subset for which the derivative map is injective but not surjective

Comment: Notice that $X$ need not have dimension $n$ because is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. For example, $\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb R^3|x^2+y^2=1\}$ has dimension $1$. So if you have a diffeomorphism $U\rightarrow X$, then $U\subseteq\mathbb R^m$ and $X\subseteq\mathbb R^m$ have the same rank and $U$ has rank $m$, being open, while $X$ need not have dimension $n$. You can actually have a smooth map $\phi:U\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$, for all $n\geqslant m$ by sending $(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ to $$(x_1,\cdots,x_m,0,0,\cdots,0)$$then $\phi(U)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ of rank $m$ and $\phi:U\simeq\phi(U)$

Comment: @Alessandro I agree that $U$ is diffeo to $\phi(U)$ but the question mentions it is diifeomorphic to $X$. From your last example it is not clear to me why $X$ can have more dimensions than $U$ and yet be diffeomorphic.

Comment: It doesn't have an higher dimension, it's just a subset of space ($\mathbb R^n$) with an higher dimension. In my example, $X$ has dimension $m=\dim U$ (with the map $\phi:U\rightarrow\phi(U)=X$ as the unique chart on $X$).

Comment: Also, the derived map $df:TM\rightarrow TN$ of a diffeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ is always 1-1 and onto. The inverse function of $df$ is $df^{-1}$, where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse diffeomorphism of $f$